# In spark, does the the underlying Hadoop layer replicates the data to a replication factor?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop2

In spark we have RDDs and hence data replication is not done , but if spark is installed over YARN , does the underlying HDFS replicates the data to nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `Spark` does makes data replication, which is related to `RDD Persistence`, please refer to https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence.

Comment: Okay agreed, but if the data is spilled to HDFS , then as per Hadoop will it be replicated to the replication specified in configuration file

Answer (score 0):

if you save the output of a spark job to HDFS the files will be replicated by Hadoop. otherwise if you need replicated persistence while spark is processing the date you should call persist with a storage level that uses replication (MEMORY_ONLY_2, MEMORY_AND_DISK_2, etc.)